# How to minimize Soundcloud's track URL length?

Tags: url, social-networking, soundcloud, podcast

When posting a soundcloud track, I wish to reduce the length of the internet address, which leads to the track. Normally the track contains the uploader's username and also the track's title.

Unfortunately [soundcloud's own URL shortener has been abolished](https://community.soundcloud.com/share-embed-230064/custom-url-shortener-6976480).
 A workaround could be, to [extract the track ID](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20580824/4287572) number, because mostly it's shorter than the track title.

How can I build a plain internet address which contains the track ID number? I tried, but it does not work.

Comment: If you want help debugging your code, you need to show that code.